# What fonts are available on Python turtle?

Tags: python, fonts, turtle-graphics

I am having trouble with changing the font in turtle.
I want the font to be Comic Sans, but when I run this code the text is in Arial:

```
write("Turtle Racer", align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 80, "normal"))
```

What fonts are available for turtle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List available font families in \`tkinter\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614027/list-available-font-families-in-tkinter)

Comment: `turtle` uses `tkinter` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my system:

```
import turtle

turtle.write("Turtle Racer", align="center", font=("Comic Sans MS", 80, "normal"))

turtle.done()
```

And is consistent with the family name returned by the code @hop left a link to in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

to use a font, it has to be the name as seen in say - word, so as opposed to Comic Sans, it would be, as previously stated - comic Sans MS

Answer (score -2):

> The below code works in my system. I have included the screen class to help visualize and for you to test it out.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
t = Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.write(arg="Your Text", align="left", font=("Comic Sans", 10, "normal"))

screen.exitonclick()
```

> If I see your code, you may have missed to call the object on which the write method is being called.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  :^)   Glad to have you here.  Please note, this answer appears to be a duplicate of the accepted answer.  If you'd like to post additional clarity on the answer, I'd suggest commenting on the previously accepted answer.

Comment: @Frodnar Thanks for the info and sorry for not using the correct area to write.