# how to get the list of the available fonts on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

how do I get a list of the names of the available font in Tkinter?

The only fonts that I tried and worked were 'Courier' and 'Helvetica', and I tried using other fonts but it returned the same default fonts.

```
# this works
button = tk.Button(self.subframe, text="quit", command=master.destroy,
                        highlightbackground='black', font='Helvectica 18')

# this does not work (the text remains the font)
button = tk.Button(self.subframe, text="quit", command=master.destroy,
                        highlightbackground='black', font='Roboto 18')
```

([font used in the second example](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?preview.text_type=custom))

so I don't know which fonts are available or not, and it would be helpful if I can get a list of the fonts.

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614027/list-available-font-families-in-tkinter/47415907

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this

```
from tkinter import Tk, font
root = Tk()
print(font.families())
```

Comment: I tried but it doesnt return anything in the terminal and a blank frame?

Comment: @coder_not_found: do `print(font.families())`.