# How to find what fonts are in my module of tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-text

How do i know what fonts are available in my tkinter? I tried the answers of others code to this question but it just won't work. Is tkinter fonts based on the installed fonts on the system or it comes preinstalled with tkinter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List available font families in \`tkinter\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614027/list-available-font-families-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

This question seemed to be answered fully [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614027/list-available-font-families-in-tkinter/39614028), along with code to see what each font will look like.

Although this may not be the fastest way, I would encourage you to look into [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOXrh5GrojM&t=1s). It will not only allow you to see every available font, but will also allow you to create more modern looking UI much faster using Tkiner library, and Python.
You can find a clearer tutorial here on how to transfer what you create to Tkinter [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf5cnJDSolE&t=334s).