# Increase font size in tkinter for large screens

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a small application in tkinter which will run on a large screen. For the audience to see something at all I need huge font sizes for some widgets.

My problem now is, that tkinter seems to ignore font sizes larger than 40:

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
for s in [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]:
    tkinter.Label(root, text=f"font size: {s}", font=("Arial", s)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: TKinter Fonts]

Is there any way to increase the font size further?

Edit:
For clarification, I am using Open Suse Linux, KDE X11. Switching to wayland does not change the output.

Comment: Your code generates six unique and correct sizes for me (Python 3.12.2, Windows 10).

Comment: It may be that your system doesn't have fonts larger than 40. On my Macintosh your code results in six unique sizes. It looks like your screenshot is using bitmapped fonts. If that's all you have, they will be a fixed size that can't scale.

Comment: It looks like that it is the issue of the `Xming` X11-server.  Try using another X11-server, like [VcXsrv](https://github.com/marchaesen/vcxsrv).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers, they gave me the right direction to look further. Some fonts on my system (Open Suse Tumbleweed, KDE, X11) are bitmap and do not scale beyond a certain size. Changing the font to something else was the easiest solution:

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
for s in [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]:
    tkinter.Label(root, text=f"font size: {s}", font=('utopia', s)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To find a vector font I used the code from this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53717785/19950163

Answer (score -1):

Your code generates the correct font sizes for me. However, I believe that the problem is with your window size, since the font size seems to be "limited" by the window. Try resizing it, or if it doesn't work, use 'root.geometry("500x400")` to resize the window in your code.
[image]

Comment: Resizing the window won't affect the font size.

Comment: Resizing does not help.